# How can I pass JSON formatted data from View to controller action in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core

I am new in.net core MVC. I want to send data from view to controller in JSON format.

I am creating dynamic table for saving data of data. post I want to send this newly added data controller.

Kindly see the logic and update me if anything I doing wrong or how can I achieve my aim.

I want to retrieve the values in SubmitExpense() method

Here is the javascript:

```js
 $(function () {
            $('#btnSave').on('click', function () {
                //alert('1111');
                var ExpenseCliamViewModel = {};
                var ExpenseClaimLineItems = new Array();
    
                $("#myTable:eq(0) TR").each(function () {
    
                    var row = $(this);
                    var ExpenseClaimLineItem = {};
                    //ExpenseCliamViewModel.ExpenseClaimLineItem.
                    ExpenseClaimLineItem.LineItemTitle = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
                    ExpenseClaimLineItem.LineItemDescription = row.find("TD").eq(2).html();
                    ExpenseClaimLineItem.ExpenseTypeName = row.find("TD").eq(3).html();
                    ExpenseClaimLineItem.LineItemAmount = row.find("TD").eq(4).html();
                    ExpenseClaimLineItem.LineItemClaimDate = row.find("TD").eq(5).html();
                    // alert(ExpenseClaimLineItem);
                    ExpenseClaimLineItems.push(ExpenseClaimLineItem);
                });
    
                ExpenseCliamViewModel.ExpenseClaimLineItem = ExpenseClaimLineItems;
                ExpenseCliamViewModel.Title = $("#Title").val();
                ExpenseCliamViewModel.Description = $("#Description").val();
                ExpenseCliamViewModel.TotalAmount = $('#lblGrandTotal').html();
    
    
               // ExpenseCliamViewModel.Title = $("#Title").val();
                console.log(JSON.stringify(ExpenseCliamViewModel));
    
                if (ExpenseCliamViewModel != null) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Expense/SubmitExpense",
                        data: JSON.stringify(ExpenseCliamViewModel),
                         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (response) {
                            if (response != null) {
                                alert('Sucess');
                            } else {
                                alert("Something went wrong");
                            }
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    }); 
                }
                else
                    alert('failed');          
                
            });
        });
```

Here is the controller C# method:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SubmitExpense(ExpenseCliamViewModel expenseCliamViewModelData)
{
 int insertedRecords = 1;
 return Json(insertedRecords);
}
```

Comment: Here I am receiving NULL values in SubmitExpense() in parameter expenseCliamViewModelData

but same I am receiving values on the the time of javascript in  JSON.stringify(ExpenseCliamViewModel)

Comment: Have you tried: `data: {expenseCliamViewModelData: JSON.stringify(ExpenseCliamViewModel)` , in your ajax?

Comment: Just tried but working for me, still receiving NULL values in SubmitExpense() in parameter expenseCliamViewModelData

Comment: Is the entire object `null` or just some of it's properties? Can you add the model to your post?

Comment: Object have properties with null values. I have made custom view model for ExpenseCliamViewModel. so properties having but nothing is coming from view

Comment: So it sounds like the ajax is working, it's something to do with your model. Can you please add your model class in your post?

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax, try :

```
 $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:"/Expense/SubmitExpense",   
        data:ExpenseCliamViewModel,
        success:function(data){alert("success")},
        error:function(){alert("error")}
    });
```

**Update:**

Change your  code `$("#myTable:eq(0) TR")` like below :

```
$("#myTable").find("tr:gt(0)").each(function () {

                ...
            });
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but with given above code I can retrieve the 1st array values not but lineItems array values. Anyhting can we do to also get child array values as well

Comment: @user3044986 Could you share your model and your full cshtml code? So that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Please see the above code I have put the both Model and CSHTML code

Comment: @user3044986 Please see my update answer.

Comment: Changes accordingly it is working for me, Thanks to all of you for your support

Comment: @user3044986 You are welcome:)    If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? If not, could you please follow up to let me know? Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thanks.